# "sudo emacs" Doesn't Work

Tags: sudo

I am trying to use `sudo emacs` with no luck so far. When I run with `--debug-init` I get the following.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory "web-mode")
```

Why would it be different when I am using `sudo emacs`? Regular `emacs` runs fine.

Comment: Consider running Emacs as a regular user, and editing files which require root permissions with [TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode).

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out - thanks!

Comment: Other options are using `sudo -e` and `sudo -E`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sudo emacs` runs as the root user. One consequence is Emacs won't look for your .emacs in the home directory of your normal user, it will look in root's home directory instead. So none of your config will be loaded, and you don't have access to any packages installed by your normal user.

As mentioned in a comment, you should run Emacs as your normal user, and use tramp to open files as root. If you're trying something more arcane, we'll need more info to help you.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu configures `sudo` such that it *does* preserve `$HOME` and Emacs will load the normal .emacs (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/issues-with-preserving-home-on-sudo)

Answer (score -1):

What worked to me after upgrading Ubuntu from 16 to 20:

1. make sure variable `package-user-dir` is pointing to place with elpa packages (smth like `"~/.emacs.d/elpa"` or wherever it is) and make sure is set in user's `~/.emacs` file
2. make symlinks in root home dir

> ```
> sudo ln -s ~/.emacs /root
> sudo ln -s ~/.emacs.d /root/
> ```

3. make sure `~/.emacs.d/` directory and children has "read" rights to non-user (like `chmod 755`) After that running `sudo emacs` seems to read all configs right