# Why does Emacs not load the init file when using sudo?

Tags: init-file, default

My Emacs [init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el) works fine in general. But, if I am in my home directory and if I execute:

```bash
pwd

    /home/pedro

sudo emacs /etc/nixos/hosts.nix
```

For some reason, this opens vanilla Emacs without my init file being loaded. In normal situations, opening a normal file and having vanilla Emacs only happens if I do `emacs -q`. For instance, `emacs -q /home/pedro/Desktop/example.txt`.

This gets even weirder for my naive eyes if I change my position on the file structure. After tweaking the position, if I try to open the same file, then Emacs works as expected being loaded with the init file. To illustrate, the following works as expected:

```bash
pwd

    /home/pedro

cd /etc/

emacs nixos/hosts.nix
```

Since this problem might be related to my OS, I must say that I am using NixOS. This is my [configuration file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config/blob/main/configuration.nix).

This does not seem to be the same situation as [this previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/sudo-emacs-doesnt-work). On the previous question, the person was unable to do a `sudo emacs`. I can always do it, but in a specific case, my init file is not been loaded.

Why does this happen?

Is there some way to do `sudo emacs /etc/host` being on `home` and with my init file being loaded?

Comment: When you open emacs as a super user, it tries to get the init file of that user. Since there's none, it starts vannila emacs. I suggest opening emacs as a normal user and opening a buffer with super user privileges, by using tramp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["sudo emacs" Doesn't Work](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/sudo-emacs-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sudo` starts a session where the user is `root`, not you. It is looking for an init file under the home directory of `root` (usually `/root` on GNU Linux). It looks in the usual places (`/root/.emacs`, `/root/.emacs.d/init.el` etc) and if it doesn't find any, it will start a vanilla emacs session (as @aadcg points out in a comment).

Try

```
sudo emacs --user pedro ...
```

to run `emacs` with an arbitrary user's init file. See the `man` page of emacs with `M-x man RET emacs` for all the options.

Depending on how you set up your `load-path` however, you might have problems: e.g. I use `$HOME` in my `load-path` to pick up several libraries, but that expands to `/root` in the `sudo` session, so those libraries are not found. One way is to symlink `/root/libdir` to `/home/pedro/libdir` in such cases, one symlink per library directory. Another way is to reorganize your init file to not use `$HOME`. A third way is to provide a `/root/.emacs` that sets some things up and then loads your init file with `(load "/home/pedro/.emacs.d/init.el")` or similar - the setting up I mention would provide impedance matching between the root environment and whatever your init file requires.

---

In general however, it's not a particularly good idea to be running emacs (or a shell) as root: too many opportunities to really damage your system. `sudo` should be used for targeted operations that *have* to be done as `root`.

@aadcg in another answer provides a function that uses `tramp` to create a "sudo-ed" buffer for the same file. I use `tramp` directly to do the same thing without the function, but it amounts to the same thing.

I sometimes don't bother with `tramp`: to edit a file as root, I do `sudo ed <file>`, running the ancient line editor as root under a command shell within emacs no less, causing untold amounts of mirth for anyone watching :-)

Answer (score 4):

@NickD solves the issue from one perspective. There's another way to go about it.

Open emacs without `sudo` and, whenever you need root privileges to edit a file, use the following command:

```lisp
(defun my-sudo ()
    "Use Tramp to sudo the current buffer."
    (interactive)
    (when buffer-file-name
      (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```